# If $(X_{nj})_{1 \le j \le n}$ are iid for each $n$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{n} X_{nj} \to N(0,1)$ in distribution, do we have $X_{n1} \to 0$ in distribution?

Tags: probability-theory

We have a triangular array $(X_{nj})_{1 \le j \le n}$ of real random variables, where each row consists of iids. Would it be possible to have the convergence $\sum_{j=1}^{n} X_{nj} \to N(0,1)$ in distribution while having $X_{n1} \not\to 0$ in distribution? Note that $X_{n1} \to 0$ in distribution is equivalent to saying that $(X_{nj})_{1 \le j \le n}$ is a null array.

Answer (score 0):

No, $X_{n}$ necessarily $\to 0$ in distribution.Consider a compact interval $[-N,N]$. Let $\phi_n (t)=e^{itX_{n1}}$. The $(\phi_n(t))^{n} \to e^{-t^{2}/2}$ uniformly on $[-N,N]$. It follows from this that $\phi_n$ has no zeros in $[-N,N]$ for n sufficiently large (independent of t). By a well-known result this implies $\phi_n$ has a continuous logarithm on $[-N,N]$, say $\psi_n$. Now $n \psi_n (t) \to -t^{2} /2$ so $\psi_n (t) \to 0$ and $\phi_n (t) \to 1$. Hence $\phi_n (t) \to 1$ for all t proving that $X_{n1} \to 0$ in distribution/probability.